# How to use dynamic CodeStar connection ARN in CodePipeline source stage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

To integrate GitHub with CodePipeline, I am using CodeStar connections (GitHub Source V2). In CodePipeline source stage, I have to specify the connection ARN. The problem is, the connection ARN contains UUID and not a reusable name. If I have to recreate a connection, the ARN will change and the pipeline also needs an update.

Is there a way that I can take the Connection ARN from SSM parameter (or something of that type) and use that in the pipeline source configuration, so that I don't have to update the pipeline in case the connection resource need an update?